# Tap my foot... Piedbatas?

Tags: single-word-requests

To tap one's foot to the beat of the music, what is the expression in Esperanto? PIV says „piedbatas la plankon”, but I'm not sure. Using „piedbati” seems more like "kicking the floor", not "taping one's foot". I am not sure it would be right to say, „piedfrapeti” either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

- *piedklaki/piedtamburi/piedbati laŭritme de la muziko*
- *bati per la piedo la takton de la muziko*

Comment: Dankon! Mi ŝatas „piedtamburi laŭritme...”. En Duolingo mi dirus, „have a lingo.”

Answer (score 0):

Mi dirus tion jene:

```
Akompani (la) ritmon per piedo/fingro
```

*akompan-* [havas muzikan signifon](http://vortaro.net/#akompani), kio igas ĝin taŭga en tiu ĉi kunteksto.